# como iterar en un dataframe con bucle for

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, jupyter

Tengo una lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de iterar con un bucle for en un dataframe para consultar una data en un webservice:

```
value=[]

for i in range(0, 10):
    nit = mydataset_df.CO_tin_no
    url = 'http://www.rues.org.co/RM/ConsultaNIT_json'

    headers, payload = {
            'Content-Type':
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, {'txtNIT': nit}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=4)
    if r.json().get('rows', False):
        res = r.json()['rows'][0]
        legal_name = res['razon_social'].title()
        value.append(legal_name)
        print value
        #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = value
    else:
        legal_name = 'no existe el numero %s' %nit
        value.append(legal_name)
        print value
        #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = value
   # print (row["name"], row["age"])
```

El resultado no es el esperado, itera sobre el mismo elemento y la respuesta es la misma.

```
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
[u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto', u'Pardo Jose Gilberto']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo resuelto, asi quedo:

```
 for i in range(0, 10):
    print 'esto es i =', i
    nit = mydataset_df.iloc[i]['CO_tin_no']
    print 'valor de nit', nit
    url = 'http://www.rues.org.co/RM/ConsultaNIT_json'

    headers, payload = {
            'Content-Type':
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, {'txtNIT': nit}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=4)
    if r.json().get('rows', False):
        res = r.json()['rows'][0]
        legal_name = res['razon_social'].title()
       #value.append(legal_name)
        print legal_name
        print '##############################################'
       #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = legal_name
    else:
        legal_name = 'no existe el numero %s' %nit
       #value.append(legal_name)
        print legal_name
        print '**********************************************'
       #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = legal_name
```

y el resultado obtenido es:

```
esto es i = 0
valor de nit 190xxx71
Pardo XXX yyyy
##############################################
esto es i = 1
valor de nit 860xxx85
Alberto XXXX yyyy XXXX. Ltda
##############################################
esto es i = 2
valor de nit 90xxxxxx51
Abastecedor xxxx YYYY xxxx S A S
##############################################
....
```

Gracias por las respuestas y colaboración!

Answer (score 0):

Estás iterando sobre el mismo campo una y otra vez. Reemplazá el `0` por la variable `i`:

```
value=[]

for i in range(0, 10):
    nit = mydataset_df.CO_tin_no
    url = 'http://www.rues.org.co/RM/ConsultaNIT_json'

    headers, payload = {
            'Content-Type':
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, {'txtNIT': nit}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=4)
    if r.json().get('rows', False):
        // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        // Hacé el cambio aquí
        // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        res = r.json()['rows'][i] 
        legal_name = res['razon_social'].title()
        value.append(legal_name)
        print value
        #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = value
    else:
        legal_name = 'no existe el numero %s' %nit
        value.append(legal_name)
        print value
        #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = value
   # print (row["name"], row["age"])
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Dependiendo de la data que estés leyendo, significa que el índice se está saliendo de la cantidad de campos en la fila.

Comment: como elimno el index? index=false

Comment: No, no... Es decir, la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo `r.json()['rows'][]` es inferior a 10. Te sugiero depurar el código para ver qué hay dentro del arreglo y así determinar cuál es el tamaño máximo a usar en la variable de iteración.

Comment: pero el diez (range(0,10)) hace referencia a la cantidad de lineas con la que debe iterar el bucle... no es asi? es decir quiero que recorra 10 lineas desde el 0.

Comment: Entonces, validá si en esa consulta, `r.json()` vienen más de 10 filas

Comment: hay 13 keys en el diccionario, pero falla en la segunda vuelta del bucle

Comment: Entonces, debe ser un error en la consulta de los registros. Te sugiero depurar el código para ver el resultado, principalmente lo que está en la variable `r`.

Comment: Estos son los valores de cada vuelta en la iteracion [IMAGEN](http://nimb.ws/F5Ndf0)

Answer (score 0):

El bucle principal está mal implementado. Tienes lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    nit = mydataset_df.CO_tin_no
    [...]
```

En cada iteración del bucle estás asignando a `nit` la columna *completa* llamada `CO_tin_no`. Esta columna es una `Series` pandas, que en muchos contextos python tratará como una lista.

Cuando más tarde haces:

```
headers, payload = {
        'Content-Type':
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }, {'txtNIT': nit}
```

en el payload estás metiendo un diccionario con clave `'txNIT'` y valor `nit`, que ya vimos que era la columna completa. Seguramente cuando `requests` serialice ese valor para pasarlo a JSON le pase una lista con todos los "nit" de la columna. Y en todas las iteraciones del bucle le pasas la misma columna completa, por lo que no es raro que la respuesta sea también siempre la misma.

Entiendo que no es lo que querías, sino que querías pasar un solo "nit" por iteración del bucle. Cámbialo por tanto para que sea:

```
for nit in mydataset_df.CO_tin_no:
    [...]
```

**PD**: No descarto que pueda haber otros errores, pues no puedo probar el código. Comenta si aparecen más problemas.